# Does a Historical Traffic Chart for the Stellar Lumens Platform Exist?

Tags: transactions, lumens, data

I'm aware of https://dashboard.stellar.org/ to view live platform transactions, but I would like to access a historical growth chart. As new apps and tools get brought on board, and as more people transact with Lumens, I'd like to have access to review true transaction platform growth.

Does a chart or an online tool exist for this data? For example, I'd like to see a chart of daily transaction volume over one or two years on the network.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Steller Expert](https://stellar.expert/explorer/) offers some of this information.